# org-mode with bug tracker jira

Tags: org-mode

i am keen on using jira with `org-mode` . [org-jira-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OrgJiraMode) looks like a potential candidate but i use `HTTP REST` in most scenarios, and i don't want to break my head with `soap` protocol for the sake of `org-jira-mode`. 

Is there any other jira plugin that does its talk through the  `rest` protocol?

Comment: There's this but it is very old and unmaintained: https://github.com/mattdeboard/jira-rest

Comment: There is also a CLI utility which could be integrated into Emacs: https://github.com/ototo/jic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [org-jira](https://github.com/baohaojun/org-jira) which got recently support for the REST API in a separate [restapi branch](https://github.com/baohaojun/org-jira/commits/restapi).

Haven't had the time to test it myself yet, though.  Just happened to be looking for something like this some time ago.

Comment: org-jira [appears to be moving](https://github.com/melpa/melpa/pull/4411) to https://github.com/ahungry/org-jira

Answer (score 1):

@idontgetoutmuch and @stsquad commented the question but the links in their comments in my opinion count as answers:

- [jira-rest.el](https://github.com/mattdeboard/jira-rest) (very old and unmaintained)
- [JIRA Command Line Client](https://github.com/ototo/jic) (could be integrated into Emacs)